# How to insert Multiple Criteria into Index Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently, I have an index-match exercise whereby I have to return the value matching 3 criteria.

1. Find the Date in the spreadsheet
2. Find a specific subheading under the Date of the spreadsheet (Same column as the date)
3. Find a specific column.

I cannot match line by line. I would need to use index match such that it can apply to further dates

I have already tried inputting different formulas but each of them returns N/A

```
=INDEX('[XX.xlsx]FF'!$A:$BY,MATCH('[XX.xlsx]FF'!$A:$BY = "Net")*('[XX.xlsx]FF'!$A:$A = W3),0),MATCH(1,'[XX.xlsx]FF'!$A:$BY=LEFT("Dec - 20",8),0))
```

Note: W3 mentions the specifc date I am trying to find in the spreadsheet
Subheading is "Net"
And the column I am trying to find is "Dec - 20"

If all these line up, it should return a number. However, it does not.

Could someone spread some light on how I can approach this. I can provide further details if needed.

Comment: Really needs a screenshot showing what needs to be matched.

Comment: or a small set of sample data with expected output will help.

Answer (score 0):

The general formula is as follows:
    =INDEX(Table1[Col D],MATCH(1,(Table1[Col A]="E")*(Table1[Col B]="F")*(Table1[Col C]="G"),0))

[image]